# What is a "Battle Video" and how do I watch one?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

For an example of context, see [this forum post](http://www.smogon.com/forums/showpost.php?p=3445572&postcount=336).

The user references a "battle video" by number (in the format XX-XXXXX-XXXXX).  Obviously this is meant as some kind of public number to be put in somewhere to watch that specific battle.  How does this work?  Where can I watch battles referenced like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature was [originally introduced](http://www.serebii.net/platinum/battlerecorder.shtml) in Pokemon Platinum, I believe.  To create and view videos in Black or White, you need get the VS Recorder from Nimbasa City and then go to a Pokemon Center in Unova to access the Global Terminal.  For more details, see http://www.serebii.net/blackwhite/wifi.shtml